# Access function variable values without arguments

Tags: c

I am with a problem which consists in print some value of a function(FOO) with another function(RECOVER), but recover is a void function without arguments. How could I access the foo variables ?

Example:

```
int foo(int a, short b, char c){
   int x, y, z;
   x = a;
   y = b;
   z = c;
   recover();
}

void recover()
{
    How can I print the x y z values here ?
}
```

PS: I can create another function that would help me to do it. Could I access these values using the register values ? Or pointers ?

Thank you guys

Comment: Tagging this as C and as C++11, makes no sense. Which language are you using? That said, I don't think this is really a programming question, the programming answer would be "don't do that, if you need the values of x, y and z, pass them in arguments". It's basically just a puzzle, isn't it?

Comment: I am using C language, but the "puzzle" basically is take the values of x, y and z without arguments.

Comment: Okay, removed the C++11 tag then. There are possible answers, but they'll almost certainly be highly system-specific, and actually not valid (standard) C, which is why I won't post such an answer myself.

Comment: @Augusto: You could serialize variables of `foo` into some file, then deserialize in `recover`. So no arguments passed, but imho it does not make much sense in practical meaning. Other "hackish" ways are system-specific as @hvd already pointed.

Comment: You could make them global. @GrzegorzSzpetkowski global variables are a lot more sane than your idea.

Comment: @immibis: How can variables be global and defined locally in `foo` (i.e. `x, y, z` belongs to `foo`) at the same time?

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski Ugly hacks like `#define recover() globalx=x,globaly=y,globalz=z,recover()` before `foo`'s body, and `#undef recover` after it. :) But I don't think that's allowed, the question only mentions allowing creation of another function, not macros.

Comment: It's not my rules. I have to use these variables locally in the function foo.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski the same variable can't be both, but it should be obvious that you can have separate variables which are global.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve this sensibly the only way to do so is to use pointers (or references in C++).

As currently written the question is somewhat ill-posed because there is no requirement for `x,y,z` to actually exist in memory *anywhere* in your program as they're unused. A decent optimising compiler will notice this, emit no redundant code and warn you in the process. As an example gcc on x86 produces the following code for `foo`:

```
foo:
    rep ret
```

I.e. all the function does is return. (It doesn't even call recover since the call to recover provably doesn't do anything yet).

Let's assume though that we've disabled all optimisations at all and have a really naive compiler. We're also going to have to disregard all notions of standard C and portability and instead rely on our knowledge of specific compiler implementation details, calling conventions and specific platforms to go any further.

On Linux x86 with gcc 4.8.2 the default calling convention is to push arguments onto the stack, such that the left most argument (a) is at the top, followed by b until the right most argument (c) is lowest in the stack. So to call `foo(1,2,3) you'd expect code like:

```
push 3
push 2
push 1
call foo
```

to be generated. Notice here that although the types are different sizes the generated code is identical for each, that is to say that `char` gets the same amount of stack space as `int` does when passed as an argument like this. (That's advantageous because it allowed the alignment of the stack to remain predictable which ensures that no slow unaligned loads are ever required and we can always count on the aligned instructions being sufficient).

In reality the code that my version of GCC actually generated was:

```
subl    $12, %esp
movl    $3, 8(%esp)
movl    $2, 4(%esp)
movl    $1, (%esp)
call    foo
```

This is most likely an optimisation over push, even with optimisations turned off, but it has the exact same semantics just using explicit stack pointer addressing. (Probably it either takes fewer bytes to represent, or it allows modern processors to be a few clock cycles quicker in at least some circumstances).

There's another important point to note here, which is that on x86 the stack grows "down". (That's just the rule which stuck from a long time ago where it probably once allowed for efficient use of limited address space and keeps load/store instructions shorter in terms of bytes required).

So once we enter the function `foo` Our stack looks like:

```
ESP + 0 ==> a 
ESP + 4   > b 
ESP + 8   > c
```

Inside the function `foo`, because we've told the compiler not to do any optimisations the code looks roughly (I removed some bits that aren't relevant to this discussion) like:

```
foo:
        pushl   %ebp           ; Save EBP as it was when we were called
        movl    %esp, %ebp     ; Update EBP to be what the stack pointer was
        subl    $24, %esp      ; Reserve 24 bytes of stack space, for locals and to maintain 16 byte alignment
        movl    12(%ebp), %edx ; copy 'b' into register edx
        movl    16(%ebp), %eax ; copy 'c' into register eax
        movw    %dx, -20(%ebp) ; copy just the low 16 bytes of edx into a temporary variable on the stack
        movb    %al, -24(%ebp) ; copy just the low byte of eax into a temporary variable on the stack
        movl    8(%ebp), %eax  ; copy 'a' into register eax
        movl    %eax, -12(%ebp); copy eax into stack variable x
        movswl  -20(%ebp), %eax; copy first temporary into eax  (as short)
        movl    %eax, -8(%ebp) ; copy eax to y
        movsbl  -24(%ebp), %eax; copy second tempoary into eax (as char)
        movl    %eax, -4(%ebp) ; copy eax to z
        call    recover
        leave
```

Ebp has a similar role to esp, except that it points to where the top of the stack was when the current function got called, not where the top currently is. This is useful and common on x86 because we can trivially address both our arguments, as ebp+(4*n) and local variables as ebp-(4*n) using this base pointer.

From the code above we can conclude several things:

1. Compiling with optimisations disabled is a terrible idea - even some redundant code that does nothing ends up wasting both stack space and time. (This extra work presumably just stores everything somewhere safe always and avoids trying to figure out if any other code can overwrite the inputs somehow).
2. Inside `recover` we can't recover all the variables just by reading registers. (The register allocation internally reused them in this case).

If we were on Windows, using fastcall and had only 2 arguments to recover we could do so by reading ecx and edx *provided* the didn't get overwritten internally. On x86_64 where there are far more registers to play with and a different argument passing convention then reading from the register might also be viable, even in this case.

So from the code we've read so far we can see that the variables we're after are stored on the stack, just after (since it grows down) ebp.

For our recover function therefore we want to read directly off the stack, using what we've learned from the generated assembly code to find x,y and z. There are two ways to do this both of them are totally non-portable and make assumptions about the stack layout and compiler far far beyond anything in standard C.

### Method 1:

For this method we're going to use some inline asm to directly 'capture' the value of ebp as was in the previous function. As well as the arguments that get pushed on the stack there are two more entries, that are less obvious. Firstly when the `call` instruction happens it actually saves eip, the instruction pointer onto the stack implicitly. (This is needed to allow the return instruction to figure out where to actually return to). Secondly the first thing most functions do is save ebp on the stack to restore it later. (Though do note that not all functions do this, some functions don't use ebp at all or use it as a general purpose register instead and this is basically up to the compiler to decide).

So within `recover`, at the earliest point we can actually write any code the stack actually looks like:

```
ESP    ==> 
ESP+4  ==> Old ebp value
ESP+8  ==> Old eip value
ESP+12 ==> Padding/local variables for previous function
.... More local variables, followed by padding and arguments to previous function
```

So what we're going to do is to read the old Ebp value off the stack and then find x,y,z relative to that at -12, -8 and -4 respectively:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void recover() {
  register void *old_ebp;
  asm("mov (%%ebp), %0"
      : "=g" (old_ebp));
  printf("old ebp was: %p\n", old_ebp);
  int *locals = ((int*)old_ebp) - 5; // Note 5*4
  printf("%d %d %d\n", locals[0], locals[1], locals[2]);
}

int foo(int a, short b, char c) {
   int x, y, z;
   x = a;
   y = b;
   z = c;
   recover();
}

int main() {
  foo(1,2,3);
  return 0;
}
```

Which when run prints something like:

```
old ebp was: 0xbfd51d38
1 2 3
```

Notice that in the code above the offset we used to find the start of the locals was -5. This is because as I was writing the code above the stack layout changed from the annotated code I showed to start with. That should give another pretty good hint about how much of a bad idea finding variables like this really is.

### Method 2

Rather than explicitly read ebp and find the old ebp value we can search relative to a local variable in the current stack frame. My implementation of this method was:

```
void recover() {
  int tmp;
  int *locals = &tmp + 11;
  printf("%d %d %d\n", locals[0], locals[1], locals[2]);
}
```

I found the specific value (11) required here empirically using a debugger - it's a measured distance on the stack from the locals in my function to the locals in the caller I care about. You can do that in GDB with  something like the following:

```
Breakpoint 1, foo (a=1, b=2, c=3 '\003') at test.c:5
5      x = a;
(gdb) i r ebp
ebp            0xbffff528   0xbffff528
(gdb) p &x
$1 = (int *) 0xbffff514
(gdb) p &y
$2 = (int *) 0xbffff518
(gdb) p &z
$3 = (int *) 0xbffff51c
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, recover () at test.c:13
13    int local=0;
(gdb) i r ebp
ebp            0xbffff4f8   0xbffff4f8
(gdb) p &local
$4 = (int *) 0xbffff4f4
```

This uses 'info registers' (i r), 'print' (p), 'breakpoint' (b) to stop at the right places.

So the distance between `local` and `x` on the stack is 0xbffff514-0xbffff4f4 is 0x20 in the example debug session. Divide that by 4 (since we need pointer arithmetic, not bytes for the expression as written) and we get the distance on the stack for a given compiler+program+platform.

Be warned with this method the compiler could quite happily generate *any* code since this is undefined per the C standard. At least with method 1 it fits the GCC specific `asm` syntax.

### Method 3:

We can also use another trick to read the locals from the previous function. Recall that the arguments to our function are positive relative to ebp/esp at function entry. The locals we're looking for are also positive relative to ebp/esp, so if we trick the compiler into thinking there are more arguments to our function than the caller supplies we can read the old locals as arguments:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int a, short b, char c) {
   int x, y, z;
   x = a;
   y = b;
   z = c;
   recover();
}

void recover(int l1, int l2, int l3, int l4, int l5, int l6, int l7, int l8, int l9, int l10, int l11, int l12, int l13, int l14, int l15) {
  printf("%d %d %d\n", l13, l14, l15);
}

int main() {
  foo(1,2,3);
  return 0;
}
```

In the code above we simply define enough arguments to skip over the stuff on the stack we don't care about until we find the locals of the previous function call.

This relies upon the fact that C assumes the function `recover` returns an int and takes no arguments, but the definition does not match up with that assumption.

### Conclusion

This is so utterly utterly compiler/platform dependent that you really don't want to do it. Even for a given case the compiler doesn't really have to make any promises.

If you really wanted to do this in practice don't! You can get the same behaviour in one of two ways:

1. Pass pointer/references into `recover` (recommended)
2. Use global variables instead of local ones inside `foo`
3. Use the debug information from the compiler (programatically if you want) to make the detail of "where does this variable live?" the compiler's problem again and not have to worry about more than DWARF/PDB.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Flexo. I will read everything with calm and attention.
I know it isn't practical, but it is a homework so I have to follow the rules.

Comment: Flexo, How can I find the empirically value using the debugger ? Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you have debug information available to use? What debugger do you use? (I can explain for either windbg or gdb)

Comment: I am using gdb however I don't have a lot of experience using these tool.

Comment: @Augusto GDB sample session added - it doesn't quite match the worked examples from previously as I didn't quite use the same sample program but it shows the method needed.

Answer (score 0):

if you prefer to print x,y.z pass them as reference in case of C++, in c you can depend on pointers. Example on how we can achieve it in C++ is given below:

```
#include<iostream>


void recover(int &x, int& y, int& z)
{
    std::cout<<"x:"<<x<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"y:"<<y<<std::endl;
}

void  foo(){
   int x, y, z;
   x = 1;
   y = 2;
   z = 3;
   recover(x,y,z);
}

int main()
{

    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't use argument in the recover function.